# RSACryptoServiceProvider - where does the seed data is being generated?

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have the following code that generates public and private keys using RSA.

```
// generate RSA 1024
                using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024))
                {
                    var publicString = RSACryptoService.ExportPublicKeyNoHeaderFooter(rsa);
                    var privateString = RSACryptoService.ExportPrivateKey(rsa);

                    rsaKey = Convert.FromBase64String(publicString);
                }
```

> My question is on how does `RSACryptoServiceProvider` generates everytime a random one, does it uses kind of a seed that is based on hardware or on timestamp?

Comment: Random variables are generated in Net using a DateTime object as the seed to the random number generated.  RSA you can provide your own string as a seed for the private variable so you can use the same private variable on encryption and decryption and not send the private key where hackers can get the get.

Comment: @jdweng: As Eric Lippert [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58738519/18192), cryptographically secure random number generation is entropy-based, not seed-based.  While it is possible to perform seed-based secure random number generation, at that point your seed is better described as a key; it better be generated securely.

Comment: That is not exactly what Eric is saying.  The seed isn't just using the time, but other factors as well.  I just didn't get into all the details of the inputs into the seed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how does RSACryptoServiceProvider generate a random seed? is it based on hardware or on timestamp?

It depends on what hardware is available and what operating system you're running on. If you're running on Windows, the entropy for the seed can come from several sources:

- There may be hardware on the machine dedicated to producing crypto-strength randomness.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module
- The hardware/firmware that controls the boot sequence -- what we used to call the BIOS -- may provide crypto services. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface.
- Modern Intel and AMD CPUs have a random number generating instruction that gets randomness from the hardware. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RDRAND
- Modern chips usually have a high-precision clock; the lower bits of it can be used as a source of entropy.
- If none of the above is available, Windows can fall back to the old fashioned approach of using keyboard timings, disk timings, mouse timings, and so on, as sources of entropy.